# Create softlinks to a file in every subfolder

Tags: linux, command-line

I have some webspace on which I can't edit the main `php.ini` file, and I can't use an `.htaccess` command to make it recursively applied.

If we call my web directory `D`, I'd like to recursively create a softlink in every subdirectory of `D` (and every subdirectory under those, etc) to a `php.ini` file in `D`.

Is there a single command line statement that could be used for this?  If so, what is it?

I'm using a Linux-based host.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bash 4+ solution (with globstar enabled, `**` is a recursive glob and `**/` will expand to every directory, recursively):

```
shopt -s globstar
for f in ./**/; do ln -s php.ini "$f"php.ini; done
```

POSIX solution with find -- this will work on any *nix:

```
find . -type d -exec ln -s php.ini '{}'/php.ini \;
```

Either of those should be run in the directory D. `ln -s` is the command to create a symbolic (soft) link on *nix, you can check out further information about it with `man ln`.

To remove the links afterwards, you can again use either bash (assuming version 4+) or find:

```
shopt -s globstar
for f in ./**/php.ini; do [[ -L "$f" ]] && rm "$f"; done
```

The `[[ -L "$f" ]]` tests to see if $f is a soft link, and `&&` means 'only do the next thing if the previous evaluates to true' -- so this won't get rid of your original 'php.ini' file.

```
find . -type l -name 'php.ini' -delete
```

`-type l` (that's a lower-case L, not a one) tells find to look for symbolic (soft) links only, which means that it won't find & delete your original 'php.ini' file.

Comment: Thanks!  That does create the softlinks... (unfortunately, I've got to go back to the drawing board on how I'm going to approach the original problem)  If I want to remove them later, I could make the globstar look like: `for f in ./**/; do rm php.ini; done`  Right?

Comment: `for f in ./**/; do rm "$f"php.ini; done`, actually (your guess would only remove the original php.ini file, not any of the soft links). Or, even better: `rm ./**/php.ini`. Both of those will remove the original `php.ini` too, though; the easiest way around that is to rename the original first with something like `mv php.ini php.ini.backup`, and then name it back when you're done getting rid of the links. It's possible to avoid the renaming workaround using `find . -mindepth 2 -type f -name 'php.ini' -delete` -- see `man find` for more information.

Comment: D'oh, brainfart -- that would find regular files, and *not* symbolic links; instead you should use `find . -type l -name 'php.ini' -delete` (that's a lowercase l, not a 1).